# Not able to use background substractor module in opencv

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0, mog

I am trying to use background Substractor module in opencv. I am referring this [blog](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html#gsc.tab=0). I am not able to use it because I again and again get the error message `'module' object has no attribute 'createBackgroundSubtractorMOG'` , I have go-ogled through all the answers to this problem and I have tried using all the substrings possible like - `createBackgroundSubtractor` , `BackgroundSubtractor` , `createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2` etc. but I again get the same error message. I am using -

- opencv 3.0.0
- python 2.7.10
- ubuntu 15.10

here's my code--

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG(detectShadows=True)

while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)

    cv2.imshow('frame', fgmask)
    k = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if(k == 27):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Got my question solved. What i did , I opened python command line and wrote `dir(cv2)` and it listed me all the functions I can call and there I found `BackgroundSubtractorMOG` and it worked!